# xdg-open opens a different application to the one specified by xdg-mime query

Tags: debian, xdg-open

I run Debian Jessie without a desktop environment (I use the tiling window manager i3) and like to use `xdg-open` to quickly open files using a preferred application.  I have an ongoing problem setting the preferred app for PDF files though. This is my problem in a nutshell:

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype ~/Downloads/document.pdf
application/pdf

$ xdg-mime query default application/pdf
/usr/share/applications/qpdfview.desktop

$ xdg-open ~/Downloads/document.pdf
[opens gimp!]
```

Any ideas would be hugely appreciated - this has been plaguing me for about a year.  The only way I've ever managed to (temporarily) fix it is by directly editing the `mimeinfo.cache` and removing the reference to `gimp` from the `application/pdf` record.

And yes, `/usr/share/applications/qpdfview.desktop` exists and contains the correct location of the `qpdfview` binary.  (Indeed, this .desktop file is used when I hand-edit `mimeinfo.cache`.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could attempt to manually set it via the command line using `mimeopen`.

#### Example

```
$ mimeopen -d ~/test.pdf

Please choose a default application for files of type application/pdf

    1) E-book Viewer  (calibre-ebook-viewer)
    2) Document Viewer  (evince)
    3) Xournal  (xournal)
    4) GNU Image Manipulation Program  (gimp)
    5) Xpdf PDF Viewer  (xpdf)
    6) Print Preview  (evince-previewer)
    7) Inkscape  (inkscape)
    8) calibre  (calibre-gui)
    9) Other...

use application #2
Opening "/home/saml/Downloads/test.pdf" with Document Viewer  (application/pdf)
```

Which results in my PDF file, `test.pdf` opening up in Evince. From this point on Evince is the default when I use `xdg-open`.

#### References

- [How to get a list of applications associated with a file using command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114075/how-to-get-a-list-of-applications-associated-with-a-file-using-command-line/114089#114089)
- [Is there an "open with" command for the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124811/is-there-an-open-with-command-for-the-command-line/124813#124813)

Comment: Thanks!  I still don't know why the problem existed in the first place, but at least the default now seems to persist beyond an apt-get dist-upgrade.

Comment: @Tim - glad this resolved your issue.

Comment: Why does this work, but setting the default application using `xdg-mime` doesn't work? This is the kind of stuff that drives me insane! To elaborate, I tried `xdg-mime default /usr/share/applications/evince.desktop application/pdf`, and `xdg-mime query filetype /some/file.pdf` confirmed that the default application was set, but `xdg-open` completely ignored my preferences and opened Print Preview instead.

Comment: @Hubro `xdg-open` is a shell script wrapper for opener commands of various desktop environment. I guess you could try running `sh -x $(which xdg-open) /some/file.pdf`, figuring out which actual opener command is  called, then hope to find out where to searching for next...

Comment: @sim Sorry but why was this the accepted answer? The answer seems to provide a workaround (it does not in my case) but does not actually answer the issue of why xdg-open ignores the xdg-mime query.

Comment: @sim I can confirm that the tip of using the sh -x command helped in my case as it allowed me to track down that the opener command was shuffling things to gnome-default-applications-properties, after which I could correct the default application via the gnome file browser.