# xdg-open just opens Nautilus

Tags: fedora, gnome, kde, mime-types, xdg-open

I'm running Fedora 20 with Gnome 3.12. Recently, I installed KDE via `yum` but decided to stick with Gnome. Ever since installing KDE, the `xdg-open` and `gnome-open` commands do not open files with the associated applications but will instead open Nautilus, selecting the file. Double-clicking the file in Nautilus will then open the associated application.

For example:

```
[user@host ~]$ xdg-mime query filetype test.pdf
application/pdf
[user@host ~]$ xdg-mime query default application/pdf
evince.desktop
[user@host ~]$ xdg-open test.pdf
[user@host ~]$ gnome-open test.pdf
```

but both of the last two commands open Nautilus. On the other hand, `kde-open` *does* work, opening evince (and writing some `kioclient` stuff to stdout, don't know whether that's of any relevance):

```
[user@host ~]$ kde-open test.pdf
kioclient(27111) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12" 
kioclient(27111) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12" 
kioclient(27111) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12" 
kioclient(27111) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12" 
kioclient(27111) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12" 
kioclient(27111) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12" 
kioclient(27111) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12" 
kioclient(27111) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12" 
kioclient(27111) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12" 
kioclient(27111) KMimeTypeRepository::parents: "/usr/share/mime/subclasses"  refers to unknown mimetype  "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slide.macroEnabled.12"
```

I'm aware of [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134352/xdg-open-opens-a-different-application-to-the-one-specified-by-xdg-mime-query), but using the `mimeopen` command did not solve my problem.

I didn't uninstall KDE so far because I'm not sure exactly how and I don't want to break stuff. However, any solution involving getting rid of KDE would be acceptable given some pointer as to how.

Comment: Have you installed xfce or check whether `exo-utils` installed? removing it may help you. (visit similar stuff: [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/35602/256099) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/53225/256099)). If this may help, let me know to add answer

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Some update of Fedora along the away apparently fixed the issue for me, though.

Comment: ok. no-probem if it is fixed