# Why does xdg-open use Mendeley as default for PDFs?

Tags: configuration, mime-types, defaults, xdg, xdg-open

Similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/939027/69674), I have some applications (Calibre, texdoc) open PDFs with Mendeley. Opening PDFs from Thunar, Thunderbird, Firefox etc. opens evince, the expected default.

It seems that those applications use `xdg-open` since:

```
$ xdg-mime query default application/pdf
mendeleydesktop.desktop
```

I [tried to find](https://askubuntu.com/a/964932/69674) where this comes from but was unsuccessful; I fixed it with

```
xdg-mime default evince.desktop application/pdf
```

The question remains: where did `xdg-open` get the idea that Mendeley should be the default PDF viewer from?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with i3 4.11. `xdg-open` is at version 1.1.0 rc3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question remains: where did `xdg-open` get the idea that Mendeley should
> be the default PDF viewer from?

This is an eminently reasonable question.
Here's a somewhat long answer in three parts.

## Option 1: read the documentation

For example, the [FreeDesktop standard](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-1.0.1.html)
on mimetype associations has this to say:

> **Association between MIME types and applications**
>
> Users, system administrators, application vendors and distributions can
> change associations between applications and mimetypes by writing into a
> file called mimeapps.list.
>
> The lookup order for this file is as follows:
>
> ```
> $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/$desktop-mimeapps.list            user overrides, desktop-specific (for advanced users)
> $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mimeapps.list                     user overrides (recommended location for user configuration GUIs)
> $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS/$desktop-mimeapps.list            sysadmin and ISV overrides, desktop-specific
> $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS/mimeapps.list                     sysadmin and ISV overrides
> $XDG_DATA_HOME/applications/$desktop-mimeapps.list for completeness, deprecated, desktop-specific
> $XDG_DATA_HOME/applications/mimeapps.list          for compatibility, deprecated
> $XDG_DATA_DIRS/applications/$desktop-mimeapps.list distribution-provided defaults, desktop-specific
> $XDG_DATA_DIRS/applications/mimeapps.list          distribution-provided defaults
> ```
>
> In this table, `$desktop` is one of the names of the current desktop,
> lowercase (for instance, kde, gnome, xfce, etc.)

Note that if the environment variables such as `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` and `XDG_DATA_HOME` are not set, they will [revert to their default values](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/ar01s03.html).

> `$XDG_DATA_HOME` defines the base directory relative to which user specific data files should be stored. If `$XDG_DATA_HOME` is either not set or empty, a default equal to $HOME/.local/share should be used.
>
> `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` defines the base directory relative to which user specific configuration files should be stored. If `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is either not set or empty, a default equal to `$HOME/.config` should be used.

This illustrates one of the trickiest aspects of mimetype associations:
they can be set in many different locations,
and those settings might be overridden in a different location.
However, `~/.config/mimeapps.list` is the one that we should use to set our own associations.

This also matches the [documentation for the GNOME desktop](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/mime-types-application-user.html.en).

> To override the system defaults for individual users, you need to create a
> `~/.config/mimeapps.list` file with a list of MIME types for which you want
> to override the default registered application.

There's also this helpful tidbit:

> You can use the gio mime command to verify that the default registered
> application has been set correctly:
>
> ```
> $ gio mime text/html
> Default application for “text/html”: myapplication1.desktop
> Registered applications:
>   myapplication1.desktop
>   epiphany.desktop
> Recommended applications:
>   myapplication1.desktop
>   epiphany.desktop
> ```

The cross-platform command to check mimetype associations is:

```
xdg-mime query default application/pdf
```

For GNOME, the command is:

```
gio mime application/pdf
```

For KDE Plasma the command is:

```
ktraderclient5 --mimetype application/pdf
```

When I look at my `~/.config/mimeapps.list` file,
it looks something like this:

```
[Added Associations]
application/epub+zip=calibre-ebook-viewer.desktop;org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
<snip>
application/pdf=evince.desktop;qpdfview.desktop;okularApplication_pdf.desktop;<snip>
<snip>
[Default Applications]
application/epub+zip=calibre-ebook-viewer.desktop
<snip>
application/pdf=evince.desktop;
```

You can see there only one entry for `application/pdf` under `[Default Applications]`;
so `evince.desktop` is the default handler for PDF files.
I don't have Mendeley installed, but one way to make it the default PDF handler
is to put its desktop file here instead of `evince.desktop`.

Notice we're trusting the documentation here that `~/.config/mimeapps.list`
is the correct file; we don't actually know that for sure.
We'll come back to this in part 3.

## Option 2: read the source code.

`xdg-open` is a shell script that behaves differently
depending on the value of `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`.
You can see [how this works here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-utils/-/blob/9816ebb3e6fd9f23e993b8b7fcbd56f92d9c9197/scripts/xdg-utils-common.in#L270):

```
if [ -n "${XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP}" ]; then
  case "${XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP}" in
     # only recently added to menu-spec, pre-spec X- still in use
     Cinnamon|X-Cinnamon)
       DE=cinnamon;
       ;;
     ENLIGHTENMENT)
       DE=enlightenment;
       ;;
     # GNOME, GNOME-Classic:GNOME, or GNOME-Flashback:GNOME
     GNOME*)
       DE=gnome;
       ;;
     KDE)
       DE=kde;
       ;;
```

Since you are using `i3`,
the `DE` variable will be set to `generic` and the script will call
its [`open_generic()` function](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-utils/-/blob/9816ebb3e6fd9f23e993b8b7fcbd56f92d9c9197/scripts/xdg-open.in#L403),
which in turn will call either `run-mailcap` or `mimeopen`
depending on what is installed.

Note that you can get some extra information
by setting the `XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL`, e.g.

```
XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=4 xdg-open ~/path/to/example.pdf
```

However, the debug information is not that informative for our purposes.

## Option 3: trace the opened files.

From the previous investigations,
we know that mimetype associations are stored in files somewhere on the hard drive,
not e.g. as environment variables or `dconf` settings.
This means we don't have to rely on documentation,
we can use `strace` to determine what files the `xdg-open` command actually opens.
For the `application/pdf` mimetype, we can use this:

```
strace -f -e trace=open,openat,creat -o strace_log.txt xdg-open /path/to/example.pdf
```

The `-f` is to trace child processes since `xdg-open` doesn't do everything by itself.

The `-e trace=open,openat,creat` is to trace just the syscalls `open`, `openat`, and `creat`.
These are from the man page from `man 2 open` or [online](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html).

The `-o strace_log.txt` is to save to a log file to inspect later.

The output is somewhat voluminous,
but we can ignore the lines that say `ENOENT (No such file or directory)`
since these files do not exist.

You can also use other commands such as `xdg-mime` or `gio mime`.
I found that `gio mime` read these files in my home directory:

- `~/.local/share//mime/mime.cache`
- `~/.config/mimeapps.list`
- `~/.local/share/applications`
- `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`
- `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list`
- `~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`

It also read these system-level files:

- `/usr/share/mime/mime.cache`
- `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`
- `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`
- `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications`
- `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/mimeinfo.cache`

To look for `application/pdf` associations, this should do the trick:

```
grep 'application/pdf' ~/.local/share//mime/mime.cache ~/.config/mimeapps.list ~/.local/share/applications ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list ~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache /usr/share/mime/mime.cache /usr/share/applications/defaults.list /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/mimeinfo.cache | less
```

From here you can see where Mendeley's desktop file is getting added.

> I have some applications (Calibre, texdoc) open PDFs with Mendeley. Opening
> PDFs from Thunar, Thunderbird, Firefox etc. opens evince, the expected
> default.

Firefox and Thunderbird have [their own default application settings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400152/make-firefox-respect-xdg-mime-association).
I believe `texdoc` relies on `xdg-open`.
I'm not sure about Thunar,
but I doubt it is relying on `xdg-open`.

So ultimately this is probably due to:

- `xdg-open` having different fallbacks than other applications on `i3`; and
- Mendeley's installer adding mimetype associations in some files but not others.

Addendum: `xdg-open` should not use the `mimeinfo.cache` file on `i3`,
but if you need to regenerate it, this is the command to use:

```
update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications
```

and here is the documentation:

> **Caching MIME Types**
>
> To make parsing of all the desktop files less costly, a
> **update-desktop-database** program is provided that will generate a cache
> file. The concept is identical to that of the 'update-mime-database' program
> in that it lets applications avoid reading in (potentially) hundreds of
> files. It will need to be run after every desktop file is installed. One
> cache file is created for every directory in $XDG_DATA_DIRS/applications/,
> and will create a file called $XDG_DATA_DIRS/applications/mimeinfo.cache.

https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/0.9.5/ar01s07.html

Related:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/939027/pdf-book-opens-in-mendeley-when-openned-from-calibre
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/992582/how-do-mimeinfo-cache-files-relate-to-mimeapps-list
- [How to make xdg-open follow mailcap settings in Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472245/how-to-make-xdg-open-follow-mailcap-settings-in-debian)
- [xdg-open opens a different application to the one specified by xdg-mime query](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134352/xdg-open-opens-a-different-application-to-the-one-specified-by-xdg-mime-query)

Comment: Thanks for this very elaborate answer! I will note that documentation and reality seem to be only mildly related. _None_ of the environment variables contain any paths in my home directory, and yet an `strace ... xdg-mime query ...` list numerous files in there (similar to what you found). Also, what are these caches and when are they refreshed? Why does xdg-mime keep looking at files it _knows_ it will ignore (for `image/png`, match in first file but four more files checked). All this has quite the over-engineered look to it. Sigh.

Comment: I wrote a [little script based on option 3](https://github.com/reitzig/scripts/blob/master/xdg-mime-which.sh).

Comment: @Raphael I've update the question to explain this better, but briefly the environment variables have default values when they're not set, so `xdg-open` will still look in your home directory. Since they might be overridden later, `xdg-mime` can't skip any files. On your system, are you using `run-mailcap` or `mimeopen`? Also, I'm curious: where was the Mendeley file association stored?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications! Regarding `run-mailcap`/`mimeopen` -- not consciously, but who knows? "where was the Mendeley file association stored?" -- No idea, I changed it years back. Maybe I'll remember to check when I re-install my machine. :)