# make Firefox respect XDG MIME association

Tags: email, firefox, mutt, xdg-open

I have a website that serves dynamic eml / mbox files with a
content type of `message/rfc822`. To open them in the MUA, I
have the MIME type associated:

```
$ xdg-mime query default message/rfc822
mutt-open-rfc822.desktop
```

Likewise `~/.mailcap` and `~/.config/mimeapps.list`.

It works flawlessly in Konqueror but not Firefox 56.0. Firefox
simply ignores the .desktop file. Instead, it offers to open the
link in the editor (associated with `text/plain`).

Choosing the option “other” in the menu “Applications”, one can
navigate to and select the appropriate *.desktop* file but the
setting has no effect and the editor is restored next time the
menu is opened.

[image: firefox fail]

Setting this to “always ask” offers an option to run *xdg-open*
on it, but this loses the *content-type* and again, the editor is
chosen.

How to coax Firefox into adhering to the XDG setup?

Comment: Write a wrapper script that consists of `exec mutt -f "$@"`.  At option `other` pick the script, not the `.desktop` file.

Comment: That’s what I do anyways since I have to preprocess the EML served into a mbox for Mutt. That’s what’s invoked (with extra parms) by the .desktop file. Passing the script directly works, I know that. I just prefer GUI programs like FF to play nicely with the rest of the system.

Comment: You do understand there's a difference between what you want and what is actually implemented, right?

Comment: Firefox abides by XDG elsewhere e. g. by creating  ``XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR`` and the likes without being asked so it’s reasonable to expect it to do so in this case as well.

Comment: I didn't say it's unreasonable to expect it.  What I'm saying is it isn't implemented that way.  Don't shoot the messenger.  Please feel free to complain to Firefox developers if you disagree with that behavior.  Only Firefox developers can change it.  _shrug_