# How an application is chosen over others to open a particular filetype in Linux

Tags: mime-types, freedesktop, file-opening

Earlier my `text/xml` files were by default opened by `firefox` I think. Not sure of this because I do not remember exactly. Then I think I installed `geany` and then my `text/xml` files were always by default opened by Geany until I installed `google-chrome`. Now I see they are by default opened by `google-chrome`.

Until now I did not bother to check what are the default applications associated with a particular filetype.

Now when I check my `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` file I see this:

```
text/html=firefox.desktop;google-chrome.desktop
text/xml=google-chrome.desktop;
application/xhtml_xml=google-chrome.desktop;
```

My default browser is still set to `firefox`. The first line above shows both Firefox and Chrome for `text/html` but for `text/xml` it is only Chrome.

I think earlier it was Geany for `text/xml` because that's the reason by default Geany used to open XML files. I'm not sure on this because I've never checked.

#### Questions

- I'm wondering how it is set. How a particular application is chosen over another.
- Also how the semicolon (`";"`) is read in the file.

I'm using Fedora 20 - Mate desktop environment.

#### Query based on Answer by *slm*

Based on the Answer by @slm, I see my xml filetypes are associated with Geany.
But I see them opening with Chrome instead.

```
$ xdg-mime query default application/xml
geany.desktop
$
```

As I mentioned above my `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` file shows

```
text/xml=google-chrome.desktop;
```

So what is the difference and which should override?

Comment: What applications are you opening the files from?

Answer (score 7):

I usually use the command line tool `xdg-mime` to determine what applications are associated with a given MIME type.

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype IMAGE.PNG 
image/png

$ xdg-mime query default image/png
shotwell-viewer.desktop shutter.desktop
```

You can make this a single command like so:

```
$ xdg-mime query default $(xdg-mime query filetype IMAGE.PNG)
shotwell-viewer.desktop shutter.desktop
```

You can change the default using `mimeopen` like so:

```
$ mimeopen -d ~/test.pdf

Please choose a default application for files of type application/pdf

    1) E-book Viewer  (calibre-ebook-viewer)
    2) Document Viewer  (evince)
    3) Xournal  (xournal)
    4) GNU Image Manipulation Program  (gimp)
    5) Xpdf PDF Viewer  (xpdf)
    6) Print Preview  (evince-previewer)
    7) Inkscape  (inkscape)
    8) calibre  (calibre-gui)
    9) Other...

use application #2
Opening "/home/saml/Downloads/test.pdf" with Document Viewer  (application/pdf)
```

**NOTE:** By the way, the semi-colons are there because there can be multiple associations for a given MIME type. So `text/xml` could have `google-chrome.desktop;firefox.desktop;` as it's value would would indicate that there are 2 apps that can handle that particular type.

#### References

- [How to get a list of applications associated with a file using command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114075/how-to-get-a-list-of-applications-associated-with-a-file-using-command-line/114089#114089)
- [Is there an "open with" command for the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124811/is-there-an-open-with-command-for-the-command-line/124813#124813)
- [xdg-open opens a different application to the one specified by xdg-mime query](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134352/xdg-open-opens-a-different-application-to-the-one-specified-by-xdg-mime-query/134364#134364)

Comment: I see filetype application/xml is by default should open with geany.desktop. But the xml files are being opened by google-chrome and not geany.

Comment: Where are you opening these files after making these associations? If you use `xdg-open <file>` do they correctly open in Geany?